# cin ignores eof character ? !!! and returns -0 value of ignored eof character

Tags: c++, character, cin, eof

Here is my recursive program which reverses numbers entered before eof, but it does not stop when eof character  **^Z**  is found. Until I press enter and write eof character in new line.

example image: http://www.imageupload.org/?d=F9D743081

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void recursive()
{
    long double n;
    if((cin>>n))
        recursive();
        
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    recursive();
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You can post the demo code at http://www.ideone.com as well

Comment: That's just the way windows' command line works. `^Z` isn't a magic character, it's just something to type to tell `cmd` to close the input of the current foreground process. `cmd` only interprets it when it's the first character of a line and it waits for you to type the whole line before this happens.

Answer (score 3):

You should be writing your code as:

```
void recursive()
{
    long double n;
    if(cin>>n) // extra parens aren't necessary.
    {
       recursive();
       cout<<n<<endl;
   }
}
```

It now prints only the successfully read values. Your program would print unsuccessful read as well; the last read is unsuccessful, but your `cout` attempts to print`n` anyway.

By the way, you don't need to press `^Z` to stop the recursion. You can press some alphabets or some other non-digit characters, to stop the recursion.

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/D4XT1

Comment: if i enter: 13 21 22 ^Z ^Z ^Z ^Z recursion does not stops .. until newline I write ^Z in newline .... See Picture attached My first post ...

Comment: @David: I don't know how `^Z` is interpreted by Windows, and the stream. That I think is non-standard. That is why I suggested you to use some well-defined character.

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` is the Windows equivalent of Linux `Ctrl+D`, signaling end of input. However, console input doesn't read anything until you press Enter. On older systems the *terminal* didn't send the input to the computer until the line was complete.

Comment: Good answer but I can't help but get the feeling this is homework.